# Supported Cultures Box not available in manifest

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

This [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff637520%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) link says that to add more language to your windows phone app, you need to make changes in the supported culture box in the properties page, but I can't find such box in the properties page as well as manifest page.

I tried searching all the tabs and I have uploaded the screenshots of properties page as well as manifest, but I'm not able to find the required box.

I have developed an application and updated on the store but only English (US) is the supported language and I'm not able to localize the app.

I'm not able to add screenshots as it requires more that 10 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Adding resource files

You do not specify what languages you support in the project properties any more. You only specify the default language in the app manifest.

You have to manually add one .resw file for each language you support. The files must all be named Resources.resw and must be placed in a sub-folder, named after the language, under a “Strings” folder in your project.

Accessing resources from xaml

You access the resources by setting the x:Uid property of a control to a unique name. Unfortunately the x:Uid property is not recognized by the properties window, neither in VisualStudio nor in Blend, so you must hand code it directly in the xaml file. 
Example:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="MyTextBlock" /> <Button x:Uid="MyButton" />
<TextBlock x:Uid="MyTextBlock" />
```

You must then add a resource with the uid-name with dot-notation, that is, after the dot you write the name of the property of the control in which you want the text.

Reference : http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/22/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-localizing-apps/